# I want when i clicked to a button it change into full white page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="fullbody1">

        <svg id="icon" width="63" height="63" viewBox="0 0 63 63" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M39.9114 1.80814L62.7952 59.0791C63.5444 60.96 62.1463 63 60.0994 63H50.9285C49.7111 63 48.6274 62.2516 48.2127 61.119C43.2025 47.5746 38.1856 34.0234 33.1754 20.479C32.5934 18.896 30.3325 18.896 29.7505 20.479C24.767 34.0234 19.7769 47.5679 14.7934 61.1124C14.3787 62.245 13.2884 63 12.0709 63H2.90001C0.859807 63 -0.544922 60.96 0.204268 59.0791L23.0078 1.81476C23.4426 0.721932 24.5128 0 25.7035 0L37.2156 0C38.4063 0 39.4699 0.715309 39.9114 1.81476V1.80814ZM32.7138 39.7459L38.995 56.7079C39.5234 58.1386 38.8545 59.7281 37.4565 60.3573L32.3325 62.6688C31.784 62.9139 31.1552 62.9139 30.6067 62.6688L25.5095 60.3573C24.1182 59.7281 23.4492 58.1386 23.971 56.7146L30.2187 39.7459C30.6469 38.5935 32.2924 38.5868 32.7205 39.7459H32.7138Z" fill="#FDFDFD"/>
        </svg>`your text`
        
    </div>
`your text`
    
</body>
</html>
```

help me please, i just want a small effect where when i clicked a button the sgv turn into full white page and then it auto change into new page

Comment: You need to use JavaScript along with your existing HTML and CSS to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript along with your existing HTML and CSS to achieve what you're trying to achieve. This function should work as long as this function gets triggered via a button press. It should change the background color of the entire page to white.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('changeColorButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for replie, but i  want it more like a page transition not only it change background into white, like the svg expand bigger and then ful fill all the screen